# Alternative to the phrase "took place"?

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

My sentence looks something like this:

> Immediately after the task was complete an interview **took place**.

I'm trying to think of a good alternative to *took place*. So far all I can think of is *happened* and *occurred*, but they don't fit very well.

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus for _happened_ or _occurred_? Also, we don't know what you want special about the replacement, so all we would be doing is repeating thesaurus entries to you anyway.

Comment: @Mitch yes I've checked both words and I haven't found anything particularly suitable. I feel like more than one word may be necessary to convey what I am trying to say.

Comment: Forget everything about what you've heard about not using the passive voice (this is good advice anyway). This is a situation which seems to ***require*** the passive. How about *"... an interview was conducted".*

Comment: @Mitch the replacement does not need to be special, I have simply used *took place* in the preceding sentence, so I'm looking for an alternative. IMO the two alternatives I've suggested do not read well.

Comment: How about 'was held' then?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, good suggestion. I was trying to decide between *held* and *conducted* when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget everything about what you've heard about not using the passive voice (this is good advice anyway). This is a situation which seems to ***require*** the passive. How about *"... an interview was conducted"* (or maybe *held*)?

Answer (score 11):

How about *ensued*?

> Immediately after the task was complete an interview ensued.

Answer (score 3):

Turning the sentence around works:

> Subjects were interviewed immediately after completing the task.

or

> Subjects were interviewed immediately upon task completion.

Answer (score 1):

> Immediately after the task was complete there was an interview.

or

> X was interviewed as soon as zie had finished the task.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answers:

> - Immediately after the task was complete an interview **followed**.
> - Immediately after the task was complete an interview **turned up**.
> - Immediately after the task was complete an interview **was conducted**.

Answer (score 0):

how about the expression "came into force" ? I think it matches it very well!

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Alaeddine. When you have enough [rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) such a short post could be made as a comment.
Meanwhile, your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.
Please see the [help] to learn more about how to write a strong answer.